# How to wait for user pressed button in for loop?

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I making app but I don't know how to wait for user click button in for loop.
I want to:

- Do some code
- wait for user click button 1
- Do code
- wait for user click button 2
- continue loop

I saw this question here before but I didn't find what I need.